# Not all fields showing in PDF when using Eclipse and itextpdf

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to get data from the DB and populate a PDF.  I created a form and named the fields.  Everything was working fine before my computer crashed and I lost my code.  I had to revert back to an older version of my code. I updated my code to populate some new fields that were added on the PDF before my computer crashed. Those new fields won't show the data.

I know the problem is not within getting the data from the DB because I can populate an older field with the new data.

My first thought is that I have to initialize the new fields but I don't know where I would do that. I did a search for a field that is showing but I only saw my code where I populate that field.

QDOB1 is an older field and is populated on the PDF.

`dp.mdf("QDOB1", sChildren[1]);`

QCHILD1 is a new field and won't populate.

`dp.mdf("QCHILD1", sChildren[0]);`

I can use sChildren[0] to populate the QDOB1 field.

`dp.mdf("QDOB1", sChildren[0]);`

Here is my code for dp.mdf which populates the field on the PDF.

```
public void mdf(String uk, String vl)
  {
    if ((vl != "") && (vl.trim().length() != 0))
    {
      AcroFields af = this.ps.getAcroFields();
      try
      {
        af.setField(uk, vl);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        System.exit(0);
      }
      catch (DocumentException e)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
  }
```

Do the fields on the PDF need to be initialized? If so, where do I find the file that does this?  I can't find an XML file attached to this project.

Comment: FYI - On the PDF I looked at the properties for the field not showing the data.  It is set to 'Visable' just like the fields that are showing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the form field names are case sensitive.  It now works.